# EF4.1 ConnectionString.ProviderName returning a different class

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, connection-string

I have been trying to retrofit an excellent implementation of EF that I found [here](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/).  Unfortunately the code was written for code first implementation and I am using model first since I already have the database up and running with another application.

In the ObjectContextBuilder.cs file is the following method:

```
public ObjectContextBuilder(string connectionStringName, string[] mappingAssemblies, bool recreateDatabaseIfExists, bool lazyLoadingEnabled)
{
    this.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

    _cnStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
    _factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_cnStringSettings.ProviderName);
    _recreateDatabaseIfExists = recreateDatabaseIfExists;
    _lazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoadingEnabled;

    AddConfigurations(mappingAssemblies);
}
```

I assume the EDMX would contain the mappings that the previous method requires so I am attempting to add a simaliar method that would take in an ObjectContext of the EDMX like this:

```
 public ObjectContextBuilder(string connectionStringName, ObjectContext context, bool recreateDatabaseIfExists, bool lazyLoadingEnabled)
{
    this.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();

    _cnStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
    _factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_cnStringSettings.ProviderName);
    _recreateDatabaseIfExists = recreateDatabaseIfExists;
    _lazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoadingEnabled;
}
```

And here is the calling method:

```
    ObjectContextManager.InitStorage(new SimpleObjectContextStorage());
    var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)new SidekickEntities());
    ObjectContextManager.Init("SidekickEntities", context.ObjectContext, true);
```

When execution gets to assigning _factory I get an error that states:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

When I look at _cnStringSettings, the Provider is System.Data.SqlClient but when assigning _factory the _cnStringSettings.ProviderName is System.Data.EntityClient.

I assume this is because I am trying to use the Entity generated by the EDMX and would like to know if there is a way to get my new method to work.  I am fairly new to the EF framework and am still in a steep learning curve so please let me know if I am completely off base on what I am trying.

Here is the connection string as it is stored in App.Config

```
<add name="SidekickEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://SidekickModel/SidekickModel.csdl|res://SidekickModel/SidekickModel.ssdl|res://SidekickModel/SidekickModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=percepsrvr;Initial Catalog=Sidekick;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an existing database doesn't mean you have to use model first (fortunately). See Scott Gu's [Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx) and the TechEd 2011 screencast [Code First Development in Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV312) for details. Worked pretty well for me.

I found it very painful to use EF Model First for things it doesn't provide easily. It gets ugly very fast, especially when messsing with the EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

In case any comes across this post I found a solution to the problem which was to call an existing method in the code as follows:

```
_employeeRepository = new GenericRepository(new SidekickEntities());
```

GenericRepository is an object in the code that would take a DbContext directly.